# Always back to index page using tinymce with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, tinymce

I want to add data using textarea tinymce with ajax post. but when I click the button and I see in firebug I look at the network tab after calling the ajax page to save the data and then automatically call to the index page. But this problem only happens when I publish to hosting with web domain. everything went smoothly while on localhost. please check my code below and give me explanation and code improvement. Thank you very much.

add.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>  
<textarea class="tinymce" id="contentblog" name="contentblog"></textarea><br/> 
<button type="button" id="AjaxSubmit" name="submit">Submit</button>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugin/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea.tinymce"
});
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#AjaxSubmit').click(function (){   
        var contentblog = tinymce.get("contentblog").getContent();  
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('contentblog', contentblog);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'add-ajax.php',  
            dataType: 'text',   
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,  
            type: 'post',
            success: function(data){
                alert("Success !");
                return true;
            }
         });
    });
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

add-ajax.php

```
<?php 
include_once('connection.php'); 
$contentblog = $_POST["contentblog"];  
$data = array( 
    "contentblog"  => $contentblog  
); 
 $jsondata1 =  json_encode($data);
 $jsondata2 = json_decode($jsondata1, true); 
 $contentblog = $jsondata2['contentblog'];   
 $GetContentBlog =  addslashes($contentblog);  
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO t_test(iscontents) VALUES('$GetContentBlog')");
 if($result){
     echo 'is success';
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to block the normal form submit of the html form:

```
$('#AjaxSubmit').click(function (event ){ 
  event.preventDefault();
```

Without this the html form is submitting the form via normal http post and gets redirected!

See https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/ for more information!

Comment: thanks for your answer. but, your code not working. my page ajax cannot read or cannot other action.

Comment: What is not working? Is it still redirecting to the index page? You need to provide more information for us to help you!

Comment: sorry, I mean the code you gave there is no change. keep reading the page index when I check it from firebug on the "Network" tab.

Comment: So your are saying that you click the submit button and then no request is send to the `add-ajax.php` enpoint?

Comment: no, when click button read page 'add-ajax.php' but not get response echo 'is success'; after that the next line on firebug: Status 200 | Method Get | File / (back to index).

but actually page not redirect to index. i hope you understand what i mean.Thanks

Comment: If your php script is not returning `success` then there is a problem with your sql query. Have you looked into what the error of your sql query is via `mysqli_error($mysqli)` after you if block?

Comment: when I add the echo on the add-ajax.php page it does not read the echo. it looks like in the ajax script in the add.php page just call the add-ajax.php page and I see the parameters sent but not read the code on the add-ajax.php page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166879/discussion-between-fmk-and-achmad-darmawan).